# Docker Error waiting for container:context canceled

Tags: docker, containers, nvidia

When I tried to us the docker command `sudo docker run --gpus all nvidia/cuda:1.0.0 nvidia-smi` in centos7 linux os, I had the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused

"process_linux.go:430: container init caused \"process_linux.go:413: running prestart hook 0 caused \\\"error running hook: signal: aborted, stdout: ,
 stderr: exec command: [/usr/bin/nvidia-container-cli --load-kmods configure --ldconfig=@/sbin/ldconfig --device=0 --utility --pid=92420 /var/lib/docker/overlay/92e5814b1cb990623ac8dd1f0210c7434d530348c9f5ed626422a3e49b855131/merged]\\\\n*** Error in `/usr/bin/nvidia-container-cli':
 munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007ffe9a4e6670 ***\\\\n======= Backtrace: =========\\\\n
/usr/bin/../lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7f3e4)
[0x7f692b1943e4]\\\\n/usr/bin/../lib64/libtirpc.so.1(clntunix_create+0x8f)                 
/usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2\\\\n7f692aacb000-7f692aacf000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 134227227                  
/usr/lib64/libattr.so.1.1.0\\\\n7f692aacf000-7f692acce000 ---p 00004000 08:06 134227227                  
/usr/lib64/libattr.so.1.1.0\\\\n7f692acce000-7f692accf000 r--p 00003000 08:06 134227227                  /usr/lib64/libattr.so.1.1.0\\\\n7f692accf000-7f692acd0000 rw-p 00004000 08:06 134227227                  /usr/lib64/libattr.so.1.1.0\\\\n7f692acd0000-7f692acfc000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 137002407                  

...                     
[stack]\\\\n7ffe9a573000-7ffe9a575000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]\\\\nffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]\\\\n\\\"\"": unknown.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?